# How to print specific areas of a Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

My applications displays grouped linear data. The representation is fairly simple. The UI is divided into a few GroupBoxes in which data is displayed by TextBoxes and Labels.

Now, I'd like to print the data in a simple way. My idea is to print only the GroupBoxes and adjust the alignment so that the printed page looks a bit nicer.

What approaches can be recommended for WinForms or is there a best practice? Do there exist any predefined helper classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Control.DrawToBitmap()` method to generate an image for the control,  Which you can draw to paper in your `PrintDocument.PrintPage` event handler with `e.Graphics.DrawImage()`.

This is not a 'best practice' by a long shot.  Printers have a resolution far greater than monitors.  Typically 600 dots per inch versus 96.  To avoid getting the controls turned into postage stamps you have to rescale the bitmaps by a factor of 6.  The `PrintDocument` class does so by default.  The result is grainy, especially text looks poorly when viewed at a typical arm's length.  You'll only get good looking text with `Graphics.DrawString()`.  In other words, write code instead of copying bitmaps.  There are plenty of report generators available that help you avoid the tedium of writing the code.

Comment: Indeed. Visual Studio can create RDF projects specifically for the situation you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use the PrintForm component of the Visual Basic PowerPacks. Simply locate in the Toolbox in VS the PrintForm component and drag it onto the surface of your form. Thats all.